# How to bring HTML text in front of CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to move the text 'Welcome to my Site' in front of the moon animation, but even adjusting the z-index and position still keeps the title text hidden behind the animation. I am relatively new, so I'm unsure what to do. TIA. Here is the HTML and CSS code that I've been working on:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.moon').css("animation-play-state", "paused");
}, 20000)
```

```css
@keyframes moon {
  0% {
    box-shadow: -150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px white;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  z-index: -1;
  position:relative;
}

html {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black 60%, #041931);
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
}

title {
  font-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

#text {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.moon {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  animation: moon 20s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -10rem 0 whitesmoke;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="text">
  <center> Welcome to my Site! </center>
</h1>
<div class="moon"></div>
```

Comment: Jest set `#text` to have `position: absolute;` instead of `relative`. You dont need to make the CSS more complex.  The CSS is fine except the relative blunder.

Comment: If I change the #text position to absolute and keep everything else the same, it still doesn't show up. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I can even edit the snippet in your question, change to `position: absolute` and the text appears over the animation. The text is dark / unstyled, but this is all you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css:

```
    @keyframes moon {
  0% {
    box-shadow: -150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px white;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

html {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black 60%, #041931);
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  background: none;


}

center{
  margin-bottom:-80px;
  margin-top:80px;


}

title {
  color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

#text {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.moon {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  animation: moon 20s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -10rem 0 whitesmoke;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ozncak6g/

Comment: Woa!! How did you bring the text in front? Thank you!

Comment: Just added background:none in body{ }It was white.Also, with some minor adjustments, it's done.Yay!

Answer (score -1):

I moved your text 100 pixels from the top and gave it a red color. Seems to work fine.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.moon').css("animation-play-state", "paused");
}, 20000)
```

```css
@keyframes moon {
  0% {
    box-shadow: -150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px white;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  z-index: -1;
  position:relative;
}

html {
  background-image: linear-gradient(black 60%, #041931);
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
}

title {
  font-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

#text {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  color: red; /* For visibility */
  top: 100px;
}

.moon {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  animation: moon 20s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -10rem 0 whitesmoke;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="text">
  <center> Welcome to my Site! </center>
</h1>
<div class="moon"></div>
```